# Add a horizontal line to multiple subplots with non-numeric x axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataframe which I am plotting using df.plot and subplots.

```
            AMLR   SAag    MDB   SMDB   SWWA
All_months  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.041  0.000
Jan         0.799  0.560  0.664  0.612  0.026
Feb         0.591  0.230  0.139  0.211  0.017
Mar         0.980  0.411  0.034  0.082  0.546
Apr         0.243  0.420  0.692  0.890  0.795
May         0.302  0.880  0.706  0.850  0.334
June        0.952  0.480  0.848  0.261  0.235
July        0.369  0.480  0.055  0.970  0.658
Aug         0.953  0.530  0.184  0.241  0.523
Sep         0.761  0.450  0.650  0.271  0.723
Oct         0.151  0.047  0.000  0.004  0.690
Nov         0.672  0.500  0.001  0.043  0.834
Dec         0.557  0.170  0.012  0.039  0.007
```

Which I am plotting using

```
correlationdataplot = correlationdf.plot(subplots = True, style ='.', figsize = (10,10))
```

I want to have a line of value 0.05 plotted on every subplot. The only problem is I'm not sure how to create it since the x axis is non-numeric (ie. Jan, Feb etc).

I try using axhline as recommended in comments

```
correlationdataplot = correlationmonthsonlydf.plot(subplots = True, style ='.', figsize = (10,10))
correlationdataplot.axhline(y=0.05, xmin=0, xmax=1, colour = 'r', linestyle = '--')
```

And I get 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'axhline'

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Have you checked out `axhline`?

Comment: I try that using
  
correlationdataplot = correlationmonthsonlydf.plot(subplots = True, style ='.', figsize = (10,10))


correlationdataplot.axhline(y=0.05, xmin=0, xmax=1, colour = 'r', linestyle = '--')

And I get 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'axhline'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `axhline`

```
figure = correlationdf.plot(subplots = True, style ='.', figsize = (10,10))
for ax in figure:
    ax.axhline(y=0.05, linestyle = '--')
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(correlationdf)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(correlationdf.index)
```

[image: PLOT]